# How to use fullScreenCover with iOS 14 but sheet for 13

Tags: ios, swiftui

Imagine you've built a screen that utilizes the `sheet` API to present modal sheets, and now with SwiftUI 2.0 you want to use `fullScreenCover` instead when run on iOS 14. How do you do so? Xcode offers suggestions:

- Add if #available version check
- Add @available attribute

If you use the #available version check, it wraps all of that scoped code with #available, so you'd have to duplicate all of that to change that one line of code. If you use @available you have to duplicate the entire struct.

Is there a way to have "in-line" logic that says if iOS 14 add this modifier, otherwise fall back to this one, without having to duplicate all of the rest of the view code?

An example:

```
VStack {
    //a lot of other views here
}
.sheet(isPresented: self.$showingSomeView) { //TODO: Replace sheet with fullScreenCover for iOS 14+
    SomeView()
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is possible approach

```
struct DemoCompatibleFullScreen: View {
    @State private var activateFullScreen = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Toggle") { self.activateFullScreen.toggle() }
            .compatibleFullScreen(isPresented: $activateFullScreen) {
                Text("I'm in Full Screen!")
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func compatibleFullScreen<Content: View>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View {
        self.modifier(FullScreenModifier(isPresented: isPresented, builder: content))
    }
}

struct FullScreenModifier<V: View>: ViewModifier {
    let isPresented: Binding<Bool>
    let builder: () -> V

    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            content.fullScreenCover(isPresented: isPresented, content: builder)
        } else {
            content.sheet(isPresented: isPresented, content: builder)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Asperi How to change background color of full screen controller?